# Tracking the checkbox status and use multiple data for ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, checkbox

I have a situation here. I have two checkboxes.

```
<span class="flex-3"><input  type="checkbox" ng-model="station.val.fingerprint_scanner" ng-click="updateAccessMode(station.key,'fingerprint_scanner', station.config_group)" /></span>
<span class="flex-3"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="station.val.id_card" ng-click="updateAccessMode(station.key,'card_scanner', station.config_group)" /></span>
```

`station.val.fingerprint_scanner` and `station.val.id_card` are the values I am getting from database. And depending on the `station.val.fingerprint_scanner` and `station.val.id_card` the checkbox are checked and unchecked.

Now since I have already assigned `ng-model`. How can I get the value of `station.val.fingerprint_scanner` and `station.val.id_card` if a user has made any changes. Depending on the current situation. I have directly called a function `updateAccessMode()` and assigned a static value like this

```
reqdata.access_mode = JSON.stringify({
    "id_card" : true,
    "fingerprint_scanner" : true
})
```

So according to this no matter what if a checkbox is clicked id_card and fingerprint_scanner are always gonna be true. Basically I have hard coded values over here. Now I want these value to be true or false depending on the checkbox status. Now I have already used `ng-model` .So I am confused here how am I gonna track the checkbox status.

One possible solution I can think of is binding multiple values with `ng-model`. But I think it is not recommended. Or is there any other best solution ?

**NOTE : This checkboxes are in `ng-repeat`. I don't want to change the `ng-model`**

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-checked="station.val.fingerprint_scanner"` instead of `ng-model="station.val.fingerprint_scanner"` and use the `ng-click` for updating the required value or even assign it to `ng-model="station.key.fingerprint_scanner"`.

Its hard to provide exact solution as you have not shared your ng-repeat code and what the function `updateAccessMode()` does

Comment: `updateAccessMode` is just updating depending on the checkbox values

Comment: I get that its updating something depending on the checkbox value. But whatever its updating , can it be accessed via the `ng-mode`l ? If so you don't need the `updateAccessMode` at all. As I said in my answer, you can assign that path to the `ng-model`. Providing more information on your code helps to get a better answer/solution to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I figured out this solution. I came to know I don't need two way data binding for check boxes so I removed `ng-model`. Sorry about that misunderstanding. And used `ng-checked` as mentioned by @Karthikeyan, +1 for that. And updated the check box status based on their index.
Here is the html

```
<span class="flex-3"><input  type="checkbox" ng-checked="station.val.fingerprint_scanner" ng-click="updateAccessMode(station.key,'fingerprint_scanner', station.config_group, $index)" /></span>
<span class="flex-3"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="station.val.id_card" ng-click="updateAccessMode(station.key,'card_scanner', station.config_group, $index)" /></span>
```

And JS for that

```
if(mode == "fingerprint_scanner"){
            reqdata.access_mode = JSON.stringify({
                        "id_card" : id_card_data,
                        "fingerprint_scanner" : !fingerprint_data
            })
}else{
            reqdata.access_mode = JSON.stringify({
                        "id_card" : !id_card_data,
                        "fingerprint_scanner" : fingerprint_data
            })
}
```